# Axios and Vue.js render form submission errors

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to render the error messages coming back from the server on a failed form submission using vue.js and axios.

#### COMPONENT:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Sign Up</p>

    <form v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit">
      <div>
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="user[email]" ref="user_email" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="text" name="user[password]" ref="user_password" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="submit"/>
      </div>
    </form>

    <ul v-if="errors && errors.length">
        {{ errors }}
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import axios from 'axios'

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        errors: []
      }
    },
    methods: {
      onSubmit: function () {
        axios.post('/users', {
          user: {
            email: this.$refs.user_email.value,
            password: this.$refs.user_password.value
          }
        })
        .then(response => {
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error.response.data.errors)
          console.log(error.response.status)
          this.errors = error.response.data.errors
        })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

#### CONSOLE.LOG ERRORS

```
{email: Array(1), password: Array(1)}
422
```

As you can see I'm trying to render the {{ errors }} object just to get started but no errors are showing up on the page even if the server sent back some?

Just to be clear. How can I take the form validations coming back from the server and display them on the form if any exist? Using Vue.js and Axios. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What does the response from the server look like when validation fails?

Comment: Updating now. I'll post the console.log

Comment: Not sure if it already does, but your server must respond with an error HTTP status code for axios to throw an error you can catch. E.g. 400, 401, 422, 500 etc.

Comment: It responds with a 422

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully at your console log for the response data:

```
{email: Array(1), password: Array(1)}
```

Now look at your `v-if` directive:

```
<ul v-if="errors && errors.length">
```

As you can see in the console log, your response has no `length` property so the `div` will not show.  You initialize `errors` to be an empty array, but your response is returning an object, not an array.

You either need to fix your server call to return an array of errors or change your `v-if` directive and omit the check on the `length` property.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure is this is the most idiomatic way of going about this, but this will at least get the message to the form:

```
    .catch(error => {
      this.errors.push(error.response.data.errors)
    })
```